# Having Combo Box in MS ACCESS show all possible results

Tags: ms-access, combobox, distinct

I have an extremely wide dataset with a lot of columns. Most only have only 2-6 possible options. The user may have different options in the future for these columns.

My solutions is to use MS Access to create a search form to allow the user to find records based on input, most of these columns being combo box's.

I have successfully gotten distinct values for my combo boxs and returned values, however I only get one record returned when for example selecting "Yes" even though my data set has many that match Yes. I have tried to use a LIKE encapsulated with * and even hard corded YES but get the same results. When I Choose "No" I get no results and I expected to get the one record with "No".
How can I get all the records? Also I would like my combo box to start blank and or include a blank option.

My Row Source

```
SELECT DISTINCT WeddingList.[Location Shots/drone shots] FROM WeddingList;
```

My "After Update" VBA

```
Private Sub cboLocationShot_AfterUpdate()
Dim locationShot As String
locationShot = "Select * from WeddingList Where ([Location Shots/drone shots] LIKE '*" & Me.cboLocationShot & "*')"
'locationShot = "SELECT * from WeddingList WHERE [Location Shots/drone shots] LIKE '*YES*'"
Me.WeddingList_subform2.Form.RecordSource = locationShot
Me.WeddingList_subform2.Form.Requery
```

[Screenshot of my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ohbC.png)

Comment: *however I only get one record returned* - where? This is unclear.

Comment: I edited my question, please let me know if that clarifies the problem.

Comment: Hm, this should (both) work. Things to check: are there any additional filters on the subform? -- [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271) i.e. paste your generated SQL into a new query.

Comment: I do not have any other filters on the subform. This will be my first combo box, however I will have to create many more once I get the syntax down.

Comment: Also I ran my SQL into a new query in SQL View and the output was as expected. i.e. I had to hardcode NO and YES values as I couldn't use Me.cboLocationShot but it returned all of the records that matched YES when chosen and all the records that matched NO when chosen.

Comment: What datatype is `[Location Shots/drone shots]` ?

Comment: All columns other than the ID field are Data Type "Short Text"

Comment: MS Access is a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS). As *you describe it*, this sounds like incomplete relational database design, like it's not normalized at all ("unnormalized"). Could you post a screen shot of the relationship diagram? Click the Database Tool Tab, then Relationships.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/biAHyU.jpg

Comment: I included the screenshot above (link).   One interesting thing is that If I change my AfterUpdate() code to return all records.
`locationShot = "SELECT * from WeddingList"`

I still only get the first record returned.

Comment: Okay red alert. The matrix is real. I just changed the code to `SELECT * from WeddingList Order By ID desc` and for whatever reason I got all my records back instead of only the first record. Then I excitedly used my original code coming from the dropdown `locationShot = "Select * from WeddingList Where ([Location Shots/drone shots] LIKE '*" & Me.cboLocationShot & "*')"`  and everything is now working!
Can anyone explain why this is working? Did that fact that I used ID in the order by linked something in the logic?

Comment: Confirmed! I created a new combo box and the same situation happened. At first only the first record would return. I added code to select all records, ran the form one time, then changed the code back to using the results of my combo box and it now works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what solved my problem.

`Select * FROM Mytable Order By Desc`

Run the form

Re add the logic coming from my combo box.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no column specified in the 'LIKE' match that refers to your combo box. The match will occur on the bound column - usually the first one in the combo box.

Comment: Okay can you clarify how I should alter my code? Like you said it seems to only match the first record or not depending on the option.

The column is [Location Shots/drone shots]

Comment: In your where clause, the combo box column that you are matching on can be clarified by adding the column property as shown: Me.cboLocationShot.column(0). The columns are numbered like arrays, starting with zero.  Identify the position of the column in your rowsource that you want to match on.  For example, if the column you want to match on is the 2nd one in your query, then the syntax would be: Me.cboLocationShot.column(1).

Comment: So you are suggesting 

locationShot = "Select * from WeddingList Where ([Location Shots/drone shots] LIKE '*" & Me.cboLocationShot.Column(3) & "*')"

This does not work if it is. The Where clause left side with the location you are comparing data, the right side is the condition that must be satisfied. I think in this way it would be comparing a column to a column.

So cboLocationShot is the name of my combo box, and should store the result of the combo box choice. This in general works from my tests. Now I want to look for that value in the form and get all records that match.

Comment: Thank you for the help btw! I was wondering if you were suggesting my combo box could have more than one column, which was true originally. However in order to get Distinct columns I had to no include the identity column so I am only returning 1 column.